# combining mutiple rows into an hml table row using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table with rows and columns like this

```
row1            1      2      3
row2                   4
row3               5        6
```

And this squence is repeated n number of times, this is shopping cart table for a single item.
  I need to display the same table on the next page as summary of cart contents with all fields for a product on a single line in a table like this:

```
   row1         2   3   4   5   6
```

So all fields need to be on one line and for 2nd item in cart on second line and so on.., first column (td) which is an img is to be removed, 4th, 5th and 6th one are input text fields, need to be converted to text label and on the same line as other fields of the item. I know I can get table contents with something like this: `$( "#id_of_table_clone" ).html( $( "#table_cart" ).html() );` 
How do I go about customizing the row structure to add the columns with content from rows below?

Adding image of cart contents with 2 items, I want the 'business justification', 'start date' and 'end date' as columns headers and their contents as row content values all in one row with role and description.
[image]

this is the html for the cart table

```
        <table id="table_rolecart"class="table sortable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="sorting" style="width: 5%" scope="col">
            off
          </th>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 40%">
            <span class="column-sort" >
              <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
              <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
            </span>
          Role
          </th>
          <th scope="col" style="width: 55%">
            <span class="column-sort" >
              <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
              <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
            </span>
     Description
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>

        </table>
```

And I inserts tbody items intothis table like externally from another table like this

```
$("#table_newrole img.move-row").live("click", function() {
        var tr = $(this).closest("tr").remove().clone();
        tr.find("img.move-row")
            .attr("src", "/gra/images/icons/fugue/cross-circle.png")
            .attr("alt", "Remove");
        $("#table_rolecart tbody").append(tr);
        $("#table_rolecart tbody").append('<tr style="color:black"><td colspan="3">Business Justification: &nbsp;<input type="text" name="ar_businessjust" value="" id="ar_businessjust"></td></tr><tr style="color:black"><td colspan="2">Start Date: <input type="text" style="width:70px" name="ar_startdate" value="" id="ar_startdate"> </td><td colspan="1">End Date: <input type="text" style="width:70px" name="ar_enddate" value="" id="ar_enddate"></td></tr><tr style="height:8px"></tr>');

    });
```

Comment: how is one item rendered? please also show html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well try the following, it creates table as you require:

TRY HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/HuQd8/

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="table_rolecart" class="table sortable" cellspacing="0" width="70%" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="sorting" style="width: 5%" scope="col">off</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 40%">
      <span class="column-sort">
        <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
        <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
      </span>Role</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 55%">
      <span class="column-sort">
        <a href="#" title="Sort up" class="sort-up"></a>
        <a href="#" title="Sort down" class="sort-down"></a>
      </span>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr style="color:black">
    <td>X</td><td>Role 1</td><td>Description 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color:black">
    <td colspan="3">Business Justification: &nbsp;<input type="text" name="ar_businessjust" value="business 1" id="ar_businessjust"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color:black">
    <td colspan="2">Start Date: <input type="text" style="width:70px" name="ar_startdate" value="sd1" id="ar_startdate"> </td>
    <td colspan="1">End Date: <input type="text" style="width:70px" name="ar_enddate" value="ed1" id="ar_enddate"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color:black">
    <td>X</td><td>Role 2</td><td>Description 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color:black">
    <td colspan="3">Business Justification: &nbsp;<input type="text" name="ar_businessjust" value="business 2" id="ar_businessjust"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color:black">
    <td colspan="2">Start Date: <input type="text" style="width:70px" name="ar_startdate" value="sd2" id="ar_startdate"> </td>
    <td colspan="1">End Date: <input type="text" style="width:70px" name="ar_enddate" value="ed2" id="ar_enddate"></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<table id="newTable" style="display:none">
    <thead><th>item name</th><th>desc</th><th>business justification</th><th>start date</th><th>end date</th></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<p>
    <span id="createTable">create new table</span>
</p>
Supposing all the items are enclosed inside 'tbody' tags we can proceede as follows:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#createTable").click(function(){
        var ntr='',//to store html for new table row
         rows=[],//to collect new rows
        $tbl=$("#table_rolecart tbody"),//original table
        l=$("tr", $tbl).length;//length of rows in original table's tbody section
        var row, brow, drow;
        for(var i=0;i<l;){
            row=$("tr:eq("+i+")", $tbl);//row with item name 
            brow=row.next("tr");//row with business justification textbox
            drow=brow.next("tr");//row with date textboxes

            ntr='<tr><td>'+$("td:nth-child(2)",row).text()+'</td><td>'  //add item name
                +$("td:nth-child(3)",row).text()+'</td><td>'//add description
                +$(brow).find("input#ar_businessjust").val()+'</td><td>' //add business just.
                +$(drow).find("input#ar_startdate").val()+'</td><td>'//start date
                +$(drow).find("input#ar_enddate").val()+'</td></tr>';//end date
                rows.push(ntr);
            i+=3;//we have traversed 3 rows so next one should be current + 3
        }
        $("#newTable tbody").append(rows.join(''));
        $("#newTable").show();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of showing the new table on the same page, I was wondering how to forward the content and display the table on the nextpage.gsp, I can create a template gsp and copy this table into it and include the template in my next action call?

Comment: you can create a `JSON` object instead of creating a table and pass it on to next page.

Answer (score 0):

give ID for every td that you wish to copy the content. it's easier to point since table is a bit difficult/complicated to handle